# POISSON Distribution, probability there is no flaw

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am having difficulty with part b and c. I have got part a.

This is the question:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT1kA.png]

For part a) I have $P(x=2) = (e^{-0.1}   *  (0.1)^2)/2!$

What do I do for part b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the rate to $\lambda = 1$ flaw per $10m^2$ and then use the formula $\mathbb{Pr}[X = 0] = \frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: I am confued because it asks for probability there is no flaw....I only know how to find probability there is a flaw.

Comment: Ok, count it as 0 flaws **are** there !

Comment: I get 0.37 as my answer....0 flaw makes sense!

Comment: @trueblueanil what would I do if I need to find probability of atleast 5 flaws or more in 100 meters of sample. Would I convert lambda to 10 ?

Comment: It has already been explained in detail by Henry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- If there is a mean $0.1$ flaws per square metre, there is a mean $1$ flaw per $10$ square metres
- If there is a mean $0.1$ flaws per square metre, there is a mean $10$ flaws per $100$ square metres

Use the Poisson distribution again.

Comment: it asks to find probability there is no flaw in 10 meters of cloth.

Comment: So for (b) you want $P(X=0)$ given that $E[X]=1$, i.e. $e^{-1}$

Comment: what would I do if it asks for 5 flaws atleast for c)? I have lamda = 1 from b), and I know I could subtract -1 from somewhere but just not sure what the equation to subtract 1 from would be.

Comment: $1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)-P(X=3)-P(X=4)$ though $\lambda = 10$ per hundred square metres.

Comment: I got 0.97 using this an online calculator. I used lambda = 10, is that what you get as well?

Comment: Using the R code `1-ppois(4, lambda=10)` gives `0.9707473`